# UWP/MVVM data binding in listview with a button does not work

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, windows-runtime, uwp

I have read articles about how commanding works different inside of a listview so I tried that code but when I click nothing happens. I am using Template10. Most of the example I find are for WPF which has incompatible pieces. Just need the bare minimum to get the button click to call the method below. The relevant parts of my code are :

```
  <ListView x:Name="lvMain"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding LeadSpeakerItems}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Lsi}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

...

```
       <Button Content="Details"
                                    Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=RunCommand}"
                                    Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And the code:

```
        public ICommand RunCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            LeadSpeakerItems.Add(new LeadSpeakerItem {
                VelocifyLeadTitle = "The is the lead title that says somrthing about something and her a number 234-456-3454",
                VelocifyFirstName = "BobbiMinajobi",
                VelocifyLastName = "Luciferdissikusliskus",
                VelocifyLoanAmount = 254000.00,
                VelocifyHomeValue = 278000.00
            });
        }

        RunCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnRunCommand, CanRunCommand);
    }

      private void OnRunCommand(object obj)
    {
        // use the SelectedCustomer object here...
    }

    private bool CanRunCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT 1:

How would I get that particular item when the button or the listview item is selected?  I am trying to get this piece of code run when that happens. I am missing something.

```
      set
        {
            Set(ref selectedItem, value);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing Root is your page or another control with your viewmodel as `DataContext`, you should alter your XAML to:

```
<Button Content="Details"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.RunCommand}"
        Grid.Column="1" />
```

as `RunCommand` itself is not known to your Root object, but `DataContext` (your vm) is.

Comment: it works! took me hours just for this simple change. Makes it more confusing that some answers are for WPF or other version that are not compatible with UWP when I searched for the answer on my own

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button Content="Details"
                        Command="{Binding RunCommand}"
                        Grid.Column="1" />
```

or

```
<ListView 
     x:Name="lvMain"
     DataContext={Binding}>
     ....
</ListView>

<Button 
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lvMain, Path=DataContext}"
    Content="Details"
    Command="{Binding RunCommand}"
    Grid.Column="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try use Template10.Mvvm.DelegateCommand
for example

in viewmodel

```
public ICommand ItemSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return new Template10.Mvvm.DelegateCommand<string>((s) =>
                 {
                     NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), s);

                 });
            }

        }
```

add to your page

```
<page
xmlns:Behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:vm="using:....ViewModel"
....>
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
```

in your listview

```
    <ListView x:Name="listView" ... ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListItem}" >
                   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <Core:InvokeCommandAction     Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemSelected}"     CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```